print console to pyglet window
I have a funcioning program that uses the terminal to print events, take inputs, etc.
I want to reroute all of that to a pyglet window.
Is this possible, if so, how?
Thanks a lot for answering in advance.
I saw a similiar problem, where the solution (with different gui), was simply to say:
print = gui.text

To print your event information, create a Label object and then update its text in your event handler.
Here's a minimal example that will print the mouse click event details at the bottom of the screen:

import pyglet
from pyglet.window import mouse

window = pyglet.window.Window()

log_label = pyglet.text.Label(
    "",
    font_size=16,
    x=0,
    y=0,
    anchor_x="left",
    anchor_y="bottom",
)


@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    log_label.text = f"Mouse {button} was pressed at ({x},{y})"


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    log_label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()

